# Series or Parallel 12Volt Power supply

Tags: power-supply, parallel, series

I am looking to power Four audio amplifier (TDA2030A) and Four mic amplifier with one power supply

I have no clue where to start 
1) should i wire it in series or parallel?
2) how many amp should the power supply be? 
3) should i use one PSU or two PSU?
4) how many amp should the PSU be?
5) if One amplifier circuit Blow up, that would increase the current go to the other amplifier, would it damage the other amplifiers?

Audio Amplifier TDA2030A - http://www.ebay.ca/itm/TDA2030A-Mono-15W-Audio-Power-Amplifier-Board-AC-DC-12V-Assembled-/171805068137?hash=item2800614b69:g:nUAAAOSwKrhVZbo1

[image: in Parallel or in Series]

---

So is my calculation correct? it comes to me needing a 4.04 amp power supply if i wire everything parallel

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should wire it as in the second diagram.  The first one doesn't really make sense since the amp doesn't provide 12V (to the mic).  Each amp will only draw what it requires, and you should budget about 1.5A, so I would use a 12V supply rated for at least 6A, especially if you expect all amps to run at high output.

You can get a single supply to provide all power, or if you prefer or can't find one that's big enough, you can use two 3A supplies.

If one amp fails, it will not overload the others.  But it would probably be prudent to put fuses between the main supply and each amp.